# Merge EA accounts after acquisition

Tags: azure, account

We have our Office 365/Azure EA account with a few subscriptions and many resources there. It also integrates with our Active Directory.

We recently acquire another company who also has Azure EA account with their own subscriptions and many resources there as well. They also have Azure Devops (TFS) and using their source control and pipeline there. This integrates with another AD.

After acquisition, we would like to start thinking about merging these 2 azure accounts together for tracking and managing purposes but i'm not sure if it is possible to do so, especially they're both integrated with 2 different Active Directory.

Does someone have this situation before or have some suggestion what is the best practice to handle this? Microsoft must have customers like this before.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Gary, have you figured out any solution to this scenario? I have a similar question